# Can one MBean link to another?

Tags: jmx, jconsole

I'm somewhat familiar with displaying simple data via a JMX MBean using older JDKs. What I'd like to do is have one MBean link to a couple related MBeans, making it nicer for users to access related info. Is there a good, standard way to do that?

I'd like it to work in both the HTML adapter and richer clients like JConsole (i.e. I don't want to hardcode an operation to return HTML or something like that). Ideally this could be done via an attribute, though an operation would be ok.  Perhaps I need to use some of the newer JMX features added in 1.6, such as MXBeans?

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I'm looking for something similar, but it seems like the problem is that jconsole doesn't support it.  

With MXBeans you can have MXBeans valued return values and attributes. They are mapped to ObjectNames, and jconsole doesnt have a clickable reference, it just displays the string representation of the ObjectName.

Comment: No, I haven't. Just posted a comment on [Inter-MXBean references](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2006/06/intermxbean_ref.html) in hopes the author will respond, but I don't there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My conclusion is that you can return an `ObjectName` but it will not be linked when you access your M[X]Bean from the sun jconsole application. Instead you will just be presented the string representation of the ObjectName.

However, if you implement your own JMX client you can use these returned ObjectName to look up the "linked to" M[X]Bean.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping the bundled clients would support this like the old HTML Adapter does, but even the newer Java Visual VM doesn't seem to.